# Access div first parent without ID

Tags: javascript

How can I access the parent of specific div and hide the div with its "fieldset" using javascript?

```
<fieldset class="data-row">
    <div id="test1">
        test        
    </div>
</fieldset>


<fieldset class="data-row">
    <div id="test2">
        test        
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: `this.parentNode.style.display = "none";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('test2').parentNode.style.display = 'none';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7YrJw/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `parentNode`

```
var div = document.getElementById("test2");
var parent = div.parentNode;
```

Then to hide:

```
parent.style.display = "none";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zc84L/

Answer (score 1):

It can be accomplished using a single line of code

```
document.getElementById('test2').parentNode.style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: you should not post an exact similar answer three minutes after.

Answer (score -2):

*Sorry for the jquery answer*

In Jquery

```
$("#test2").parent().toggle();
```

or

```
$("#test2").parent().fadeOut()
```

or

```
$("#test2").parent().css("display","none");
```

Comment: From the `javascript` tag description: *"Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."*

Comment: @quentin - I didn't downvote but I believe it's because you provided a jQuery solution to a problem easily solved via JavaScript

Comment: @samuel,@Felix,@Darren ok, thks